# Action script 3 hittest if statement and coordinate

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement, hittest, coordinate

I would like to know how to write this inside my hittest if statement: whenever hittest_mc y is less than the y coordinate 213, then translate hittest_mc +70.

so far I have this:

```
if (walk_mc.hitTestObject(goback_mc)) {
        hittest_mc.y<y==213 + 70;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (hittest_mc.y < 213)
{
    hittest_mc.y = hittest_mc.y + 70;
}
```

Not sure what y coord you are referring to..you mean like y on the stage?

Comment: Yes, the y coord on the stage. If that's the only way to do it then, is it possible to place an if statement inside an if statement?

edit: 
oh god, it is! Thank you! :D